# Having problems referencing a prop while mapping in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So my issue is I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeCard' of undefined

From this code:

```
var SurveyDiv = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return{
        showCard: true
    };
},    
render: function() {
    console.log(this.props.routes);
    var routesObject = this.props.routes;
    var itemSurvey = this.state.showCard ? this.props.questions.map(function (itemSurvey) {  
        return(
            <Card
            id ={itemSurvey.surveyID}
            title={itemSurvey.title}
            options={itemSurvey.options}
            type={itemSurvey.type}
            routes={routesObject}
            removeHandler={this.removeCard}>
            </Card>
        );
        }) : '';
    return(
    <div className="surveyDiv">
        {itemSurvey}
    </div>
    );
},
removeCard: function() {
    console.log("inside removeCard");
    this.setState({showCard: false});
}
});
```

So my theory is that when I say this.removeCard inside  it's referencing the var itemSurvey instead of SurveyDiv which actually contains the removeCard function. How could I get around this?

Comment: Well, referencing a function, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use to `this.removeCard` inside a function the `this` you are referencing is the function not `SurveyDiv`.

You can get around this a couple of ways:

```
var removeCard = this.removeCard;
var itemSurvey = this.state.showCard ? this.props.questions.map(function (itemSurvey) {  
    return(
        <Card
            id ={itemSurvey.surveyID}
            title={itemSurvey.title}
            options={itemSurvey.options}
            type={itemSurvey.type}
            routes={routesObject}
            removeHandler={removeCard}>
        </Card>
    );
}) : '';
```

Or use `bind` to change what `this` in your map function refers too:

```
var itemSurvey = this.state.showCard ? this.props.questions.map(function (itemSurvey) {  
    return(
        <Card
            id ={itemSurvey.surveyID}
            title={itemSurvey.title}
            options={itemSurvey.options}
            type={itemSurvey.type}
            routes={routesObject}
            removeHandler={this.removeCard}>
        </Card>
    );
}).bind(this) : '';
```

Comment: Your first example worked like a charm, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to declare it outside your map and pass it in.

```
// in render()
var removeCard = this.removeCard.bind(this);

  // inside <Card
    removeHandler: {removeCard}
```